# Is there any specific deity who cuts sins?

Tags: history, sin

As per Hinduism is there any specific deity who cuts sins or all deities cut sins?

Narada muni when cursed Lord Vishnu then Lord Vishnu told Narada to chant 'Om Namah Shivay' which would cut sins of Narada? Why?

Also, Lord Rama established Shiva Lingam to cut the sin of Brahm Hatya  (Killing Ravana).

Also, Lord Krishna told Pandavas to worship Lord Shiva to cut the sins of Mahabharata. Why Lord Krishna, Lord Rama or Lord Vishnu can't cut sins? Is it that only Lord Shiva cuts sins as he is destroyer of sins.

Comment: "Narada muni when cursed Vishnu then Vishnu told Narada to chant Om namah shivay which would cut sins of Narada?" What scripture is that from?

Comment: "Why Krishna, Rama or Vishnu can't cut sins? Is it that only Shiva cuts sins as he is destroyer of sins." No, Vishnu can certainly get rid of sins.  See verse 18.66 of the Bhagavad Gita "aham tvam sarva papebhyo mokshayishyami" - I will deliver you from all sins.

Comment: Avatar of vishnu worshippping shiva and avtar of shiva worshipping vishnu is quite common. Thats why its been said that vishnu is there in the heart of shiva and shiva is there in the heart of vishnu.

Comment: All three can cut sins. Lord Venkateswara has this gift in his name itself. Vem = sin, kaTa= to cut. Venkateswara is the manifestation of all forms of god.

Comment: There is no original sin in Hinduism. There is karma. If you want to eliminate your Karma in this life time you can dip in the waters of Lake Manasarovar and/or visit the abode of Lord Shiva in Mount Kailash in Tibet, China.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we surrender ourselves to the Supreme God (whichever name you call him, Aum, Krishna, Vishnu, Shiva, Brahman, ...), then all sins are virtually removed; i.e. we are kept away from its effects of those fruits. Same thing happens for good deeds as well. :-)

[BG 18.66](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/66)

```
sarva-dharmān parityajya
mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja
ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo
mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
```

> Abandon all varieties of Dharma and just surrender unto Me. **I shall
>   deliver you from all sinful reactions**. Do not fear.

If you worry about the past actions, then remember that, you were just a reason of something happened as a part of the grand story of God.
A person who forfeits the fruits of all his actions will be out of this illusion or the projection of the world and hence need not worry about any kind of deeds.
IMO, though your body or senses might be bearing all the good/bad fruits of your actions, your Atman will be plugged into the Param-Atman and hence you won't be able to make a difference between the senses of Happiness and Sorrow.

[BG 2.56, 2.57](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2)

> — One who is not disturbed in mind even amidst the threefold miseries or
>   elated when there is happiness, and who is free from attachment, fear
>   and anger, is called a sage of steady mind.
>
> — In the material world, one who is unaffected by whatever good or evil
>   he may obtain, neither praising it nor despising it, is ﬁrmly ﬁxed in
>   perfect knowledge.

If one makes a practice of renouncing the fruits of own actions and always concentrated on the supreme soul, then after the death he/she is destined to be liberated from all the worldly miseries in form of happiness & sorrow.

[BG 8.5, 8.6](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/8)

> — And whoever, at the end of his life, quits his body remembering Me
>   alone at once attains My nature. Of this there is no doubt.
>
> — Whatever state of being one remembers when he quits his body, O son
>   of Kuntī, that state he will attain without fail.

Comment: Please read my question once again. Thanks.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, relating to Narada being a BhaktiYogi, Vishnu would have asked him to chant "Aum Namah Sivay" so that he is plugged into the supreme soul. Now such suggestion may not suit everyone. For Karma Yogi, he would have to renounce the fruits of actions, because he may not as capable to chant mantras with great compassion. Same thing for Gyana Yogi. The solution is to plug your soul into supreme. If you worship some deity then that also go to supreme only. God will give you (via) whatever you asked from that deity. You may read the above answer in that context.

Answer (score 5):

Not specific, but the one. Lord Krishna.

In Bhagvad Gita Lord Krishna says, I am the receiver of all the prayers in the world.

This means, whether you pray to Lord Rama or Lord Shankar or Lord Ganpati, ultimate receiver is going to be Lord Krishna who will cut your sins.

Comment: Then when Narada cursed Vishnu then why Vishnu told him to chant Om Namah shivay which would cut the sin of Narada?

Comment: Aum/Om in Om Namma Shivay is itself a bhagvan shrikrishna (According to bhagvad gita)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I don't think Vishnu ever told Narada to chant Om Namah Shivaya.  Where did you get that from?

Comment: I think it is in Shiva purana.

Comment: You should cite sources.