# How listening to and reading Bhagvat Gita or the Puranas can remove sins?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, sin

It is said that if you read or listen to Bhagavat Gita then all your sins will be removed. I also believe this. But like to know, how do they remove the sins?

Comment: Related: [Is there any specific deity who cuts sins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8628/1049). Gita is for liberation. Hence, like double edged sword, it will cut sins and virtues both!

Comment: Reading Holy texts do remove sins as said in scriptures themselves. Those who are not qualified to read can hear the recitals and benefit similarly. I am not sure though how "How" in ur question can be answered.

Comment: It's said that by listing / singing /reading glories of god from  puranas and other texts ,lord himself burns all the sins , similarly like the fire which burns impurities from gold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Krishna says in Gita 18.70-71 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> And he who will study this sacred dialogue of ours--by him shall I have been worshiped through knowledge as a sacrifice; such is My judgement.
>
> And the man who hears this [Bhagavad Gita], full of faith and free from malice--even he, liberated from sin, shall attain the happy regions [lokas] of the righteous.

The 'how' does it removes sins - the grace of God as Krishna says so.

Comment: Nice, this is what i was looking for

Comment: Where can I get English translation of Swami Nilkhilananda?

Comment: @Pandya In India,  available here - https://shop.advaitaashrama.org/product/the-bhagavad-gita-pocket/